# How to find 2 dimensional array size in JNI

Tags: java, android, c++, arrays

Am here to get suggestions from you regarding my issue. Am new bee to this, i was stuck in this from yesterday, but unable to resolve it.
Am trying to find the 2d array size in JNI, but am not getting successful result.
The below code which i have. can you guys please sort out my problem.

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_imagejoiner_MyJoiner_test(JNIEnv*   
      env,
      jobject javaThis) {
   LOGV("test print");
   return 1;
 }
  JNIEXPORT void JNICALL     
  Java_com_example_imagejoiner_MyJoiner_joinNative(JNIEnv* env,
    jobject javaThis, jobjectArray jfilePaths, jstring jfinalImagePath, int   
 verticalOverlapPercent, int horizontalOverlapPercent) {

  const char *finalImagePath = env->GetStringUTFChars(jfinalImagePath, 0);

  const int imageCount = env->GetArrayLength(jfilePaths);
  int rows = 1;
  int columns = 4;

  Mat imageBuff[rows][columns];

  /*for (int i = 0; i < imageCount; i++) {
    jstring filePath = (jstring) env->GetObjectArrayElement( jfilePaths, i);
    const char *rawString = env->GetStringUTFChars(filePath, 0);

    LOGV("reading = %s", rawString);

    imageBuff[i] = imread(rawString, 1);

    if(!imageBuff[i].data) {
        LOGV("failed to read = %s", rawString);
    }

    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(filePath, rawString);
    }*/

   //Creating a 2 dimensional array from the lieaner array
   int k = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
   {
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    {
        jstring filePath = (jstring) env->GetObjectArrayElement( jfilePaths,   
      k);

        const char *rawString = env->GetStringUTFChars(filePath, 0);

        LOGV("reading = %s", rawString);

        imageBuff[i][j] = imread(rawString, 1);

        if(!imageBuff[i][j].data) {
            LOGV("failed to read = %s", rawString);
        }
        env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(filePath, rawString);

        k++;
      }
  }

  //Creating a 2 dimensional array from the 2 dimensional array
  /*for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
  {
    jstringArray filePath = (jstringArray) env->GetObjectArrayElement(   
      jfilePaths, i);

    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    {
        const char *rawString = env->GetStringUTFChars(filePath, j);

        LOGV("reading = %s", rawString);

        imageBuff[i][j] = imread(rawString, 1);

        if(!imageBuff[i][j].data) {
            LOGV("failed to read = %s", rawString);
        }

        env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(filePath, rawString);
    }
    }*/
```

Comment: That's way too much code for trying to find an array size. You shouldn't post all your code, just the smallest amount that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: as u suggested it i did it @Coeffect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `jfilePaths` is a 2D array of strings declared in Java as a `String[][]`:

A 2D array is just an object array where each element is itself an object array, one for each row. So you can find the row count by getting the length of the 2D array, and the column count by getting the first object (which will be an object array containing the first row of strings) and getting the length of that.

```
int rows = env->GetArrayLength(jfilePaths);
jobjectArray firstRow = (jobjectArray)(env->GetObjectArrayElement(jfilePaths, 0));
int columns = env->GetArrayLength(firstRow);
```

Then you can iterate through the rows and columns like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    jobjectArray currentRow = (jobjectArray)((env->GetObjectArrayElement(jfilePaths, i));
    for(j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    {
        jstring filePath = (jstring)((env->GetObjectArrayElement(currentRow, j));
        const char *rawString = env->GetStringUTFChars(filePath, 0);

        // do stuff...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi samgak.. Thank you very much for giving great solution.